# When to use "What is the..' vs 'Which is the ...' in a sentence?

Tags: word-usage, sentence-construction, word-meaning, difference

Which is the correct usage?

> 1. **What** is the best book for learning English grammar?
> 2. **Which** is the best book for learning English grammar?

Also, can you give other examples where we could use either?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I remember a rule *(roughly defined though)*! 'what' **defines**, and 'which' **selects**.

So, ask yourself. Are you asking *in general*? If yes, use 'what'. If you have certain books that you and a person whom you are asking both *know*, use 'which'. Take simpler example -"What food do you like?" is a general question. "Which food do you like?" makes you think that you have a choice or some option - Chinese or Mexican?

'what' to talk about any general book (defines), and 'which' to select (choose from a set of books both of you understand).

Answer (score 3):

It depends. You would use 1. for books in general, without having specific books in mind. You would use 2. for example if you have two books in front of you - in that case, 'which' would really indicate 'which of these two books'.

Ironically, you are almost giving another example yourself:

> Which (of the following sentences) is correct?
>
> What is the correct usage?